# Access textbox values using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across a simple HTML code where I need to access values of textbox with 'name' field and using jQuery. I tried a few things but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the link for the code:

http://jsbin.com/tepehinuqi/1/edit?html,js,output

I just want to be able to get the values based on name attribute

Comment: `$('[name="price"]').val()`

Comment: Put the code in question itself.

Comment: @Tushar i tried that but I get an empty string

Comment: at which `event` you want to read the textbox. I don't see any code for that in jsbin.

Comment: @vijayP on "Run with JS" button in the output menu

Comment: you don't have any value in any of your textbox hence you are getting an empty string.

Comment: I want it to get the input which I enter in the textbox when I click the button

Comment: "Run with JS" button is not part of your HTML. So forget about it. Do you have any other button in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```
 $("input[name=test]").val();
```